# CloudFront incomplete downloads in Europe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We are using CloudFront as a CDN for some 3D assets that are stored on our own servers. Lately, we have been experiencing some download issues in some geographical areas.
Namely, it seems that some assets are not fully downloadable from Europe (specifically Paris) i.e. the download starts properly but stops suddenly with no specific error whereas there is no problem from the US.
We have no idea of what could make an asset not working although we tend to observe the issue only for assets with a size >10Mb and for assets that are a cache miss (`X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront`).

As the issue only seems to happen in Paris it looks like our CF configuration is not the trouble.
Has anyone already experienced the same type of issue with CloudFront?

Bonus question: CDN is a vital part of most setups but I did not find clean ways to test that it is working properly. How do you make sure that your website is working properly from your main geographic areas?
I've been testing to load some page using http://www.webpagetest.org/ but it is manual work and it doesn't provide full server/browser description

Note: I have been posting the issue on the AWS forum with [more details](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=498271&#498271) and am doubling on SO as it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally seems that the issue was on Amazon side, as stated by the AWS crew in [their answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=502825#502825) to the issue.

I have no solution regarding how to monitor the CDN QoS but I'll just assume that I've to trust our CDN provider on this and change if not happy with QoS.